# I am trying to sort data coming from Firebase Firestore according to the timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, timestamp, picasso

```
 Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("patientrecords")
            .whereEqualTo("patient_id",firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .whereEqualTo("record_name",type)
            .orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PatientModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PatientModel>()
            .setQuery(query,PatientModel.class)
            .build();
```

Here I am trying to retrieve the data from firebase firestore by using Firebase query. But was unable to get the data from the firestore. When I am trying to fetch the data according to timestamp, no data is coming .

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: Is there an index created for that query?

Comment: could u plz explain about the index ? I was not aware about it.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how it can be done.